How to add a text field in payment flow for API authentication of Gift voucher?
For redeeming the vouchers sold by Stripe merchant, we need a custom payment flow to include a text field that can be submitted for API authentication and accordingly adjust the result from checkout total.  Need some direction.   Thanks

I recommend updating this question with more details/context on what you've tried so far, how you're integrating with the Stripe API, and any errors or blockers you've encountered. It sounds like you might be looking for Promotion Codes but that's a guess: https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/coupons#promotion-codes
